# Having trouble installing Tweepy

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, tweepy

I am trying to install the Tweepy module but it is throwing an error. Below is my code in command prompt,

```
pip install tweepy
```

and here is my error,

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tweepy (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for tweepy
```

I am using Python version 3.7, 64 bit. Please help me understand why this is happening.

Thanks & regards,
Sanjay

Comment: Python 3.7 is currently in alpha stage. 
Package support for alpha versions of python usually is quite spotty. Currently Tweepy does not support python version 3.7.

From the [githubpage of tweepy](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy).
> Python 2.6 and 2.7, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5 & 3.6 are supported.

So if you need to use tweepy you need to use any of the supported python versions.
 
Alternatively you can try to clone the git repository and manually install it following the instructions on the linked page. This is however not guaranteed to work. So it is not recommended!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Twython? It's Twitter's official Python library for Python for accessing the API.

Comment: Choosing between Twython or Tweepy won't matter if neither support Python 3.7, which @K. SanJjay is using

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.7 is still in alpha and may not have certain versions of modules. Try using 3.6 as i am and it works fine.