# Unable to import tweepy (Python 3.7 - tweepy 3.5)

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm facing a problem trying to import tweepy library in my code, I've tried to uninstall it and then install it again but I still get the same problem.

This is my code (error) and command line:
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: try to uninstall and reinstall with `pip install --no-cache-dir tweepy`. let me know if that solves the problem.

Comment: Same problem :(

Comment: you can try the virtual-environment thing as suggested by @samuel. or this another thing: `pip install git+https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy.git` your code is little different from the github code.

Comment: pip install git is a command that I need to do first? if yes then I got (could not find a version that satisfies the requirement)

Comment: actually tweepy library says `Python 2.6 and 2.7, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5 & 3.6 are supported.` maybe 3.7 is not compatible yet.. virtualenv with 3.6 should do the trick.

Comment: This is still an issue in May 2020...works with python 3.6

Answer (score 2):

Tweepy doesn't work with python 3.7 yet.

Similar question: [Having trouble installing Tweepy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47137849/having-trouble-installing-tweepy)

Official documentation says : https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy

`Python 2.6 and 2.7, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5 & 3.6 are supported.`

As suggested by Samuel. Create a virtual environment I would suggest go with 3.6.

And then pip install tweepy in that environment.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a virtual environment, I had the same issue when i was still using windows.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everyone, I just downloaded Python 3.6 and solved the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to install this version instead

```
pip install git+https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy
```

This command will install the GitHub's latest version

Answer (score 0):

Tweepy will not work on Python 3.7 (see reasons in below github post), instead if you are using Anaconda, create an alternative environment in Python 3.6.7 and it will work. :-)

I've been experiencing similar idiosyncrasies with wptools and other packages.

https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/1017